# Override a component inspector title bar in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, editor, inspector

Is there a way to override what is displayed in the Unity Inspector title bar? 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AddComponentMenu will override the name:

```
[AddComponentMenu("My Componet Name")]
public class MyComponetName : MonoBehaviour
{
.....
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that! Is there way to change color or add buttons to it? Just like using custom editor to MonoBehavior?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the proper path

```
[AddComponentMenu("Scripts/The Name You Want")]
public class Example: MonoBehaviour
{

}
```